# In VS code, PHP file is not working on live server

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I know it's a place to ask syntax and such questions like that but I have a problem that made me mad.
After opening and running *php* file by entering F5 I get this error:

```
cannot launch program '(file path)'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help;
```

And I also want to know if I can run an *html* code with vs that contains also *php* in it?
Because when I run the *html* code in live server *php* files doesn't run?

Your Help Will Be Highly Appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can't open a PHP file in live server.

**Steps to open PHP file in browser**

1. You have to install XAMPP.
2. After installing XAMPP, you have to go to the folder where XAMPP is installed; there you will find a folder named **htdocs** ([XAMPP folder detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuqOi.png))
3. Inside the **htdocs** folder you have to copy-paste your **Project folder**.
4. Don't forget to name your main html file as **index.php**. After this, you just have to type **localhost** in your browser url. **After this your server will be live**

Comment: if you tell me how to run a php code like debugging in vs code i ofcourse vote u:))